# Planar reflections not showing when baked reflection probes enabled

Tags: unity

I have a reflection probe that is baked that is set to capture static environment objects like buildings/terrain etc. I also have a planar reflection probe that is following the player camera which is only set to capture the player. I am trying to have both of these displaying on a surface. When I have the baked reflection probe turned on the planar reflection will not show. Are they mutually exclusive? I am using Unity 2020.1.6f1 with HDRP.

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve? Does your scene have a reflective surface (like a marble-like ground, or a wall mirror), and you want to render reflections for static and dynamic GameObjects separately?

Comment: I'm no expert on probes, so I'm not sure if this is relevant, but this link https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingReflectionProbes.html under the overlapping probes section seems to say that if you have overlapping probes one will be cancelled.  Hi, liggiorgio, I voted for you =)

Comment: @liggiorgio yes that is correct, it's an ocean surface, and yes static and dynamic objects reflected separately for performance;.